# authenticating a python script to be able to use a signing key from Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

HTTP/Rest - need to authenticate a code/token/etc in order to pass data to keyvault so that keyvault will sign data with a key in the Key Vault.

Azure has quite a few docs on how to register my app, create credentials for it in the key vault, but then for it to authenticate via OATH2 (first step is getting a code, (then later, a token?) via REST) I keep getting redirected to log in.

Am I missing something?  I want my python script to run unattended.  I have created its ID and wrote down the plaintext password it gave me that it warned would never be displayed again.  Not sure how to use REST in this case as I really cannot auth to any application, I dont really even have any application - the Azure people told me to just put ANY url in the box when I registered the APP in AAD.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use client credentials flow. In this flow you send your credentials to AAD and it'll send you back a token. Then you can call Key Vault with that.

V1: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

V2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

Comment: thanks for the links - Im still a bit confused here, with the

    &redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/permissions

as I dont really want any app or anything to be redirected to or anything - I just want AAD itself to just auth credentials so that I can then submit data to be signed by the HSM.

Comment: Ahh, that's for doing admin consent. You don't need that with Key Vault. All you need to do is make one HTTP request from your back-end.

Comment: ok thanks @juunas - I think I just need to skip ahead a bit in the doc, to the `Get a token` section...  OK I used this example from the MS docs:
`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'client_id=535fb089-9ff3-47b6-9bfb-4f1264799865&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&client_secret=qWgdYAmab0YSkuL1qKv5bPX&grant_type=client_credentials' 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token'`

Comment: of course I put in my actual tenantID in place of the `common` and put in my app's id in the `client_id` and for the scope I used the URL in my registered apps `Home page` field, url-encoded, with that .default in there as directed.  

making progress, as I forgot to urlencode the secret and got incorrect secret error - I urlencoded it and dont get secret error but now I get:

the API returned: AADSTS50001: The application named <REDACTED APP URL> was not found in the tenantnamed <REDACTED>.

Comment: I think the scope should be `https://vault.azure.net/.default` with v2, though I'm not a 100% sure on that.

Comment: yep that did it - I had also tried the https://<keyvaultname>.vault.azure.net since that is what was listed in my keyvault but that didnt work - didnt think to try it with just vault.azure.net but I now have a bearer token  THANKS!